# how do i flash gapps onto aosp android 10 without custom rom, and how do i fix my ussd and call function not working?

Tags: fastboot, bugs, aosp, android-10, gapps

i recently managed to flash gsi using fastboot instruction:

fastboot flash system system-quack-arm-aonly-vanilla.img

from
https://github.com/phhusson/treble_experimentations/releases/tag/v213

they don't have twrp for my device so i had to use fastboot.

i wanted to know

how do i flash the gapps img. file (or how can i get gapps?)

and how do i fix ussd and phone calling function which does not work?

everything else works perfectly